# Django increment Then value in Annotate Count

Tags: django, django-annotate

Let's say I have query set A.

```
A.annotate(c=Count(Case(When(name='Jack',then=I)
```

Now, each time `A.name == 'Jack'`, `c` will be set to I. How can I increment I for each time this happens? So that for the first case, `I = 1`, for the 2nd `I=2` etc.

Comment: Could you not just iterate over the queryset and count by hand?

Comment: I could, but that would end up being to costly for my `sqlite`. It's already hitting plenty of `database is locked` errors.

Comment: Don't use sqlite?

Comment: To late for that now :/

Comment: `A.annotate(c=Count(Case(When(name='Jack',then=I+1), default=I)))` ??